# Redirecting to a page with added attributes in Spark

Tags: java, web, spark-java

Let's say I have a login page. I have:

```
Spark.get("/login", (req, res) -> {
     return new ModelAndView(new HashMap<String, Object>(), "login.ftl");
});
```

And the login page is displayed when I navigate to that URL.

Now let's say I have a sign-in button on that page. When pressed it results in a POST request to the userdashboard page.

```
Spark.post("/userdashboard", (req, res) -> {
     if (authenticateFails()) {
         // How would I navigate back to the login PAGE AND DISPLAY AN ERROR
         // res.redirect("/userdashboard") will not work because it will  simply just show 
         // the login page again, with NO error. I need to send some "attributes" along with
         // the redirect.
     }
     return new ModelAndView(new HashMap<String, Object>(), "userdashboard.ftl");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try sending the POST request to the same "/login" link, and then when the credentials go through, you can GET from the "/userdashboard" page.

Alternately, you can try Query parameters ("login?user=user&pwd=pwd") for sending to the dashboard.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand you. Would you mind just writing some pseudocode?